# Rewrite resource paths to new subdomain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

We moved a main site `advancedbrain.com` to a new site/server. The old site still serves up some older content. It can now be accessed at this subdomain: `l.advancedbrain.com`.

Many of the old pages on the old server are still looking for resources using paths like:

`http://advancedbrain.com/components/com_ixxocart/images/buttons/en/buttonAddToCart.gif`
`http://advancedbrain.com/templates/abthome/images/abt_logo.png`
`http://advancedbrain.com/plugins/system/2j_tabs/2j_tabs.css`
`http://advancedbrain.com/components/com_ixxocart/content/ajax/xajax_js/xajax.js`

etc. etc.

I am trying to write a rewrite in `.htaccess` where it will look for those resources on `l.advancedbrain.com` instead of `advancedbrain.com`.

I have tried a few things but they haven't worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured this out. Here it is in hopes it will help others.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule "^/components/com_ixxocart/images/(.+)" "http://l.advancedbrain.com/components/com_ixxocart/images/$1" [NC,L,R=301]
RewriteRule "^/templates/abthome/images/(.+)" "http://l.advancedbrain.com/templates/abthome/images/$1" [NC,L,R=301]
RewriteRule "^/plugins/system/2j_tabs/(.+)" "http://l.advancedbrain.com/plugins/system/2j_tabs/$1" [NC,L,R=301]
RewriteRule "^/components/com_ixxocart/content/(.+)" "http://l.advancedbrain.com/components/com_ixxocart/content/$1" [NC,L,R=301]
```